# Is it possible for a class to contain a lambda object that captures the class its in?

Tags: c++, constexpr

Let's just say I have a Window class, and that Window class has event handlers in the form of std::function:

```
struct Event {};
struct Window
{
    std::function<void(Event)> handler;
};

Window wnd;
wnd.handler = [] (Event) { /*some fancy handler*/ };
```

From inside the handler I don't have access to the window itself, so I can either pass the window pointer to the handler, or I can implicitly have access inside the handler function to the window by capturing it. However in the capturing case I think I run into this problem:

```
struct Event {};
struct Window
{
    std::function<void(Event)> handler;
    int member;
};

int main()
{
    Window wnd1;
    
// Capture the window so I can access it inside the handler function
    Window wnd2{ [&wnd2](Event) { wnd2.member = 3; } };
    
    wnd1 = std::move(wnd2);
    // wnd1 contains a lambda object pointing to wnd2, that's invalid.
    
    Window wnd3 { [&wnd3](int) { wnd3.member = 7; } };
    std::vector<Window> wnd_vector{ wnd3 }; // Now when vector reallocates the lambda // object is invalid because of the 'this' pointer, right?
```

So then the rule I guess is: You can't have a class containing a lambda object if that lambda object has captured the outer class (IF the outer class is movable). I think this problem extends to more general cases:

```
struct MoveableClass
{
    struct Foo { MoveableClass* outer_class_object; }; 
    Foo fooObj{this};
}
```

I can handle moving this class by using custom move functions. But in the case of std::function or if it contains a lambda, then I can't move it, right?

Comment: *I can handle moving this class by using custom move functions.* You can handle this by defining move constructors. [The rule of three/five/zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Comment: This would be perfectly fine if the lambda is created inside the class, and handled properly by the constructors. Passing the lambda in from outside there is no way for the class to re-create it and handle such constructors properly. Fairly easy to make your own callable type which can handle it for you though.

Answer (score 2):

I propose you such solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct Event {};
struct Window
{
public:
    Window() = default;
    Window(std::function<void(Window &, Event)> handler)
      : handler(handler)
    {}
    Window(std::function<void(Window &, Event)> handler,
           int member)
      : handler(handler),
        member(member)
    {}

    void setHandler(std::function<void(Window &, Event)> newHandler)
    {
        handler = newHandler;
    }
    bool callHandler(Event event)
    {
        if (handler)
        {
            handler(*this, event);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    void setMember(int newMember)
    {
        member = newMember;
    }
    int getMember() const
    {
        return member;
    }
private:
    std::function<void(Window &, Event)> handler; // if it is not needed to change class members than you can use "const Window &"
    int member = 0;
};

void print(const Window & obj)
{
    std::cout << "Object: " << static_cast<const void *>(&obj) << ", member: " << obj.getMember() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Event event;
    bool callResult = false;
    
    Window wnd1;
    
    Window wnd2{ [](Window & obj, Event) { obj.setMember(3); } };
    callResult = wnd2.callHandler(event);
    std::cout << "Call result: " << std::boolalpha << callResult << std::endl;
    print(wnd2);
    wnd2.setHandler( [](Window & obj, Event) { obj.setMember(1); } );
    
    
    wnd1 = std::move(wnd2);
    callResult = wnd1.callHandler(event);
    std::cout << "Call result: " << std::boolalpha << callResult << std::endl;
    print(wnd1);
    
    Window wnd3 { [](Window & obj, Event) { obj.setMember(7); } };
    std::vector<Window> wnd_vector{ wnd3 };
    callResult = wnd_vector.front().callHandler(event);
    std::cout << "Call result: " << std::boolalpha << callResult << std::endl;
    print(wnd_vector.front());
    print(wnd3);
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Call result: true
Object: 0x7ffd57d9ccb0, member: 3
Call result: true
Object: 0x7ffd57d9cc80, member: 1
Call result: true
Object: 0x2263c30, member: 7
Object: 0x7ffd57d9cce0, member: 0
```